# Creating python data frame from list of dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data:

```
sentences = [{'mary':'N', 'jane':'N', 'can':'M', 'see':'V','will':'N'},
     {'spot':'N','will':'M','see':'V','mary':'N'},
     {'will':'M','jane':'N','spot':'V','mary':'N'},
     {'mary':'N','will':'M','pat':'V','spot':'N'}]
```

I want to create a data frame where each key (from the pairs above) will be the column name and each value (from above) will be the index of the row. The values in the data frame will be counting of each matching point between the key and the value.

The expected result should be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(4,0,0),
                   (2,0,0),
                   (0,1,0),
                   (0,0,2),
                   (1,3,0),
                   (2,0,1),
                   (0,0,1)],
                  index=['mary', 'jane', 'can', 'see', 'will', 'spot', 'pat'],
                  columns=('N','M','V'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame(sentences).T.stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts().unstack().fillna(0)

       M    N   V
can   1.0   0.0 0.0
jane  0.0   2.0 0.0
mary  0.0   3.0 1.0
pat   0.0   0.0 1.0
see   0.0   0.0 2.0
spot  0.0   2.0 1.0
will  3.0   1.0 0.0
```

Cast as int if needed to.

```
pd.DataFrame(sentences).T.stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts().unstack().fillna(0).cast("int")
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) per columns in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), replace missing values, convert to integers and last transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df = df.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(int).T
print (df)
      M  N  V
mary  0  3  1
jane  0  2  0
can   1  0  0
see   0  0  2
will  3  1  0
spot  0  2  1
pat   0  0  1
```

Or use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.stack().groupby(level=1).value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
      M  N  V
can   1  0  0
jane  0  2  0
mary  0  3  1
pat   0  0  1
see   0  0  2
spot  0  2  1
will  3  1  0
```